# unable to use jQuery Live

Tags: jquery

I have my application using jQuery heavily. The problem is that we started with jQuery 1.3.x and now we have a case where we need to use jQuery `live()`, which is available only in 1.4.x or greater. Replacing jQuery 1.3.x may cause backward compatibility issues. Can somebody suggest how can I use both libraries, or some other way?

Comment: Is there a certain method signature you want for "live", because "live(eventType, handler)" was added in jQuery 1.3?

Comment: I definitely use live with 1.3.x, though delegate is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the noConflict idea that JohnP suggested, there is a 'livequery' plugin out there that works for jQuery 1.3:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: I would give a try to livequery plugin thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: what do u think about the backward compatibilty issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `.noConflict()` method to use both : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Use .noConflict and assign the new library to another variable and use in your page.

However, I suggest that you do it on a page by page basis, if possible and just remove the old code if it doesn't break anything.